# Can I convert a jdom2.Document to Jaxb object

Tags: xml, dom, jaxb, jdom

I would like to convert a jdom2.Document object to a JaxB document. Any idea if I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Option #1**

You should be able to wrap the `jdom2.Document` in an instance `org.jdom2.transform.JDOMSource` and unmarshal that since it implements `javax.xml.transform.Source` which is one of the inputs accepted by the JAXB `Unmarshaller`.

**Option #2**

If for some reason that doesn't work, then you could do:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();

JDOMSource source = new JDOMSource(document);
JAXBResult result = new JAXBResult(jaxbContext);

t.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: :( That idn't work for me ... I tried JDOMSource source = new JDOMSource(document) but that results in null source.

Comment: @AjeetSingh - What do you mean by "that results in null source"?

Comment: may be I will explain it to you more, actually i am implemntening a JAX-RS resteasy post method, in which I am doing something, which i get a Document object, and I want that as a body / data in Response. for which I believe i need either a something which can be converted to response, and Respone.ok.entity(document) results in an error, which works fine with some JAXB object, but in this case i don't have any precompiled JAXB source generated with xjc, i have some dynamich XMLs in a jdom2.Document object, which when i want to return from post method results in an error that

Comment: MessageBodyWriter is not implemented or so for that jdom2.Document, so i thought of converting that to something like a JAXB context ... but seems like i am unable to converte a document to JAXB kind of an object without any precompiled classess defined with some .xsd schema